# Eclispe - linking resources from another folder on the file system

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

I have a folder elsewhere on the system with images I want to use in my Eclipse Android project. These images should also be able to generate ID's so I can refer them in my app (like as if you would just copy them into drawable). 
How do you do this?

Comment: For android project if you want to add images in it and want to use using its ID then it must be in Drawable folder.

Comment: phsyically aswell? cant you just refer to another folder inn the drawable folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant' have folders in the drawable folder so this isn't possible

edit: maybe using symbolic links

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

edit2: tried this just now it works alright

edit3: example, I linked my c:\drawable folder to a drawable folder in my project/res directory with

*from res directory* (needs admin for c:/ )

```
mklink /D "./drawable" "c:/drawable"
```

you can do it for individual files too without /D

Comment: what if I import/link/refer files from another folder then?

Comment: You could make symbollic links I suppose, this is not so much an Eclipse thing but a NTFS thing